# ¿Alguien sabe la solución de este problema en swift 4 con un Fallthrough?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos, swift4

[image: Error Fallthrough en Swift]

Tengo un switch con los dos casos de la imagen, donde intento describir el entero ingresado, en este caso "11" pero cuando lo imprimo por consola me ejecuta los dos casos pero en el segundo caso no está el 11

Comment: Bienvenido! Te recomiendo darte una vuelta por el [Tour de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para ver como funciona el sitio y así de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante leer [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para formular una pregunta de calidad y que esta sea bien recibida. Por favor, las imágenes de código no están bien vistas, en su lugar copia el código y pégalo en la pregunta a poder ser con el formato de código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fallthrought lo que hace es iterar en cada caso del switch, por eso se ejecuta dos veces debes eliminar el fallthrought de ambos casos, por defecto en swift no es necesario, asiq ue eliminalo y resuelves el problema